# Doesn't time dilation prevent this matter-anti matter collision?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

special relativity tells us that the clock of an object moving at relativistic velocities appears to tick increasingly slowly as its velocity approaches c. I thought up of the following experiment and am unable to identify the flaw with my argument.

an electron and a positron are placed 1m apart and released from rest. As they attract each other, their velocities increase and approach that of light, and so their clocks appear to tick increasingly slowly. As a result, their time tends to freeze as their velocities approach c. By this logic, we shouldn't be able the collision from our frame of reference in a finite amount of time.

But from experiment, we have observed them colliding and annihilating each other. What's wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 0):

If my car is headed your way at 70 mph, and if you don't get out of the way, then it is going to hit you at 70mph and do some damage.  The speed at which it hits you and the damage that it causes is completely independent of anything going on inside my car.  It doesn't make a bit of difference whether my wristwatch runs slowly (according to you or according to me or according to both of us); if it does run slowly it doesn't matter why (whether it's because of some relativistic effect or because it's a lousy wristwatch or for some other reason); it doesn't matter whether my body's metabolism is running slow (either because of some relativistic effect or some exotic disease or anything else) and it doesn't matter whether I'm asleep or in a frenzy.  A 70 mph collision is a 70 mph collision, and if I started 70 miles away (according to you) then it's going to happen in exactly one hour (according to you).

And if I accelerate --- which *means* that I'm now going *faster* than 70mph --- then it's going to take less time for me to get there, not more, again independent of how fast my watch is moving.  In our comment exchange (which I've deleted my half of to avoid clutter), you seemed to genuinely believe that if my wristwatch is running slow then my car will hit you at a lower speed.  This is easy to test by an experiment:  Buy a really bad wristwatch, strap it on, point your car at a brick wall, step on the gas and see what happens.  Please do this only as a thought experiment.

Comment: 1) I do not believe that the speeds slow down.2) your wrist watch analogy is completely flawesd: how id a bad wrist watch the same as a wtist watch in slow motion? Slow motion increases the time between any 2 intervals, not ticks of the watch.

Comment: This answer is correct. If you see two things moving toward each other, at whatever speed, those two things will eventually collide at the time you would expect based on their speed.  They may be going so fast that a clock *inside each car* appears to you to be going slow, but that makes no difference **to you** in determining when **in your frame of reference** they will collide.

Answer (score -1):

The verb "appears" by itself

> appears to tick increasingly slowly as its velocity approaches c

does not define an observer.

For the experimenter shooting an electron  on a positron it is not possible to observe a "clock"on the electron or positron to see them go slower.Elementary particles are described [here by their quantum numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) and there are no clocks.

In any case , massive particles never reach the velocity of light, and Lorentz transformations keep correct  track of particle interactions.

Comment: That's not right. OP could have said muons instead of electrons, and then said that the muons' lifetime appears to get longer as they speed up. That's a clock, and that's why we observe more muons on the surface of the earth than you would expect in the absence of time dilation. Of course OP's question doesn't make sense for other reasons...

Comment: @kaylimekay could you elaborate on why it doesnt make sense?

Comment: @kaylimekay a muon annihilating on an antimuon would have no way of "timing" (one the other). Decays are probable and need an accumulation of events , a single muon does not have a clock that another particle could observe as slower

Answer (score -1):

To me, this question can be thoughtful. Indeed, the OP's question can be better understood if we consider two chemical reactants instead of two fundamental particles. If, by any means, we can slow the time rate for these reactive chemical materials enough as they meet each other, the products may never be produced.

However, in the OP's original question, we can assume that when two fundamental particles hit each other, they would momentarily become at rest relative to the lab observer as well as to each other, and thus their clocks run faster the same as measured in each of the particle's rest frame. Therefore, their time would be *unfrozen* as they hit each other.

On the other hand, one can hit two particles in a way that one particle goes in pursuit of the other one so that the difference between the velocities is small. At the time one particle catches the other runaway one, their time seems to remain frozen since there is not a considerable change in their velocities. In this case, I think it is possible that the annihilation products appear with a delay compared to when they hit each other head-to-head. I do not know whether this phenomenon has been detected in accelerators.